# Python Sudoku Solver goes into an infinite loop, How could I limit the amount of loops within the function?

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following code that enters an infinite loop as the puzzle has many solutions.

However, I am struggling to understand how I could limit the amount of solutions printed out without affecting how the function iterates.

I tried using a while loop inside the `solve()` function but that didn't work.

```
import numpy as np

# Add the puzzle you want to solve here:
grid = [[0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5],
        [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0],
        [2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [6, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0]
        ]


def possible(y, x, n):
    global grid
    for i in range(0, 6):
        if grid[y][i] == n:
            return False

    for i in range(0, 6):
        if grid[i][x] == n:
            return False

    x0 = (x//3)*3
    y0 = (y//3)*3

    for i in range(0, 3):
        for j in range(0, 3):
            if grid[y0+i][x0+j] == n:
                return False

    return True


print(np.matrix(grid))


def solve():
    global grid
    for y in range(6):
        for x in range(6):
            if grid[y][x] == 0:
                for n in range(1, 10):
                    if possible(y, x, n):
                        grid[y][x] = n
                        solve()
                        grid[y][x] = 0
                return
    print(np.matrix(grid))
```

Comment: `for n in range(1, 10)` does not seem to fit with a 6x6 puzzle. Maybe you want `range(1, 7)` here.

Comment: Does your solution need to be recursive or can it also be iterative?

Comment: I think I have misunderstood the problem, the algorithm was first written to solve a 9x9 sudoku and not 6x6. I might have to rewrite it. But I do have a question... but im struggling to understand the function of `x0` and `y0`

Answer (score 1):

I will try here to help with reasoning for a possible approach.

I can't say much about the correctness of `possible()` (which is very important that it works correctly otherwise it could be a never terminating algorithm). On the other hand, it seems to me while assuming `possible()` is correct that the algorithm has an upper bound (thanks to the loops with range()) and since a given [sudoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku) (even with no clues) has always a finite solution set, then your algorithm should always terminate. So, better you have expectation of time complexity you are OK with for certain input sets.

A possible way is to limit your recursion depth (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it)) or pass a parameter to i.e. `solve(limit=1000)` that you decrement every time you go deeper in recursion and combine it with a boolean condition, say, a (partial) solution(s) found or so (in the general sense of such a problem, solution verification is the easiest part).

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `solve()` it will start from the very first box `i,j = 0,0`. So, if your `possible` function returns `False` for some coordinates, you never change the value to be different from 0 and will be stuck at that particular box forever.

If, you would like to still implement a recursive function, you will at least need to pass the coordinates `i` and `j` as parameters.